# How can I reduce transaction log usage when deleting from a massive table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I had this function that deleted historical data that was no longer needed from a big table with over 10 million rows

```
DELETE FROM BigTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(month,dtmtimestamp, getdate()) > 2)
```

I then tried this method to reduce the amount of space the transaction log used:

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BigTable WHERE DATEDIFF(month,dtmtimestamp, getdate()) > 2) > 0 BEGIN
    DELETE TOP 10000 FROM BigTable
    FROM BigTable
    WHERE DateDiff(month,dtmtimestamp, getdate()) > 2
CONTINUE END
```

Is this the right method? Or am I going to use up more transaction log this way?

Any tips of good methods for this?

Cheers,
Niko

**Final Answer**:

```
DECLARE @Remainder INT
DECLARE @ChunkSize INT
SET @Remainder = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM BigTable WHERE dtmtimestamp < DateAdd(month, -2, getdate()))
SET @ChunkSize = CEILING(@Remainder/100) /* Divide the total into 100 parts, whole integers only */
WHILE @Remainder BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION deletehistorical
    DELETE TOP (@ChunkSize)
    FROM BigTable
    WHERE dtmtimestamp < DateAdd(month, -2, getdate());
    SET @Remainder = @@ROWCOUNT;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION deletehistorical
END
```

The CHECKPOINT command only tell the engine to remove finished transactions from the log (in simple recovery mode) and as this query actually still keeps going each loop the transaction is still being created. So to break up the transaction I added a BEGIN and COMMIT to force the database to take those changes each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than counting the number of rows still to delete, you ought to either use `EXISTS` (so as soon as it finds a row, it returns):

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM BigTable WHERE DATEDIFF(month,dtmtimestamp, getdate()) > 2) BEGIN
```

Or sneakier:

```
select top 1 * from sysobjects /* Force @@ROWCOUNT > 0 */
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT BEGIN
    DELETE TOP 10000 FROM BigTable
    FROM BigTable
    WHERE dtmtimestamp< DateAdd(month, -2,getdate())
CONTINUE END
```

Where the only searches of the table are ones that are used to do actual deletes.

I've also moved around your date logic, in case the dtmtimestamp column has a useful index.

*Edit* of course, as Martin points out, neither of these address transaction log usage.

The strategy of limiting deletes is a reasonable one to stop horrendous log usage, but needs to also have lots of log backups or truncates happening at the same time, to allow old transaction log space to be reused. Otherwise, it's still going to grow the log.

If you know log backups are occurring, say, every fifteen minutes, you might want to pause your loop every "n" iterations, with a WAITFOR DELAY, so that you know that the previous transaction log usage has been backed up/cleared. Whatever happens, as long as you're deleting rather than truncating, a log record for each deleted row is still going to take up space in the log or a log backup.

If you're able to take whatever is normally using this system offline, and the volume of rows which you want to keep are vastly dwarfed by the ones to delete, you might want to copy the rows to keep into another table, remove all foreign keys, truncate the table, copy the kept rows back, and rebuild the foreign keys. YMMV.

Comment: Ok the plan is now to use the sneakier method.

I am using simple recovery mode so there is no backups being done, but I imagine that charging through thousands of deletions is creating a lot of stuff in the transaction log and that needs to clear itself on occasion. So maybe a WAITFOR DELAY would fix that.

Comment: I have a question. I only see examples for deleting a lot of rows for only one table. What if I need to delete millions of records from let's say 6 tables. Does this "10000" way works? Or do I have to it separately?

Answer (score 1):

change the recovery mode to simple for the database, make updates/deletes, then change back to previous recovery mode.

Comment: the normal recovery mode for this database is already simple but it still blew out to 250GB when deleting a few million of the rows :/ How, I am still not sure

Answer (score 1):

Since your database is in simple recovery, have your script issue

`CHECKPOINT 1;`

commands after every N-iterations to free up log.

Answer (score 0):

Under the simple recovery model, an automatic checkpoint is queued if the log becomes 70 percent full. 
Limiting the max log file size in db properties will prevent the log file to grow out of bounds.